Exception caught by widgets The following _TypeError was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#e199a]: Null check operator used on a null value
this is the widget UI
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/navigation/navigation.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/pages/AddVehicle/presentation/controllers/add_vahicle_controller.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/pages/home/sheets/sheet_controller/details_update_controller.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/utilities/common_textfield.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/utilities/google_font_text_style.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/utilities/gradient_button.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/utilities/helper_widget.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/Extension/text_field_extenstion.dart';

class showVehicleScreen extends GetView<ShowVehicleController> {
  showVehicleScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _addVKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: backAppBar(title: "Add Vehicle"),
      body: GetBuilder<ShowVehicleController>(builder: (controller) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: _form(),
            ),
            GradientButton(
                name: "Submit",
                onTap: () {
                  Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.qrScreen);
                }).marginOnly(bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  _form() {
    return Form(
      key: _addVKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          vGap(20),
          _vehicleType(context: Get.context!),
          _brandFieldView(context: Get.context!, readOnly: true),
          _modelFieldView(context: Get.context!, readOnly: true),
          _registrationNumberFieldView(context: Get.context!, readOnly: true),
        ],
      ),
    ).paddingSymmetric(horizontal: 15);
  }

  _vehicleType({required BuildContext context}) {
    return Container(
      width: Get.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.grey.shade100,
        boxShadow: lightShadow,
      ),
      child: verticalDot(context),
    );
  }

  verticalDot(context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      elevation: 1,
      underline: const SizedBox(),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      value: controller.dropDownValue, 
      isExpanded: true,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      items: controller.vehicleType.map((String items) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: items,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: Get.width,
            child: Text(items, style: BalooStyles.baloonormalTextStyle()),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: null, // Disable dropdown
    );
  }

  _brandFieldView({required BuildContext context, required bool readOnly}) {
    return CustomTextField(
      hintText: "Brand",
      controller: controller.brandController,
      textInputType: TextInputType.name,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      readOnly: readOnly,
      focusNode: controller.brandFocusNode,
    );
  }

  _modelFieldView({required BuildContext context, required bool readOnly}) {
    return CustomTextField(
      hintText: "Model",
      controller: controller.modelController,
      textInputType: TextInputType.name,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      readOnly: readOnly,
      focusNode: controller.modelFocusNode,
    );
  }

  _registrationNumberFieldView(
      {required BuildContext context, required bool readOnly}) {
    return CustomTextField(
      hintText: "Registration Number",
      controller: controller.registrationNumberController,
      textInputType: TextInputType.name,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      readOnly: readOnly,
      focusNode: controller.rgFocusNode,
    );
  }
} 


cotnroller.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/response_model/vehical_list_model.dart';
import 'package:moto_park/services/APIs/post/post_api_service_impl.dart';

import '../../../../main.dart';
import '../../../../utilities/custom_flashbar.dart';

class ShowVehicleController extends GetxController {
  late TextEditingController registrationNumberController;
  late TextEditingController brandController;
  late TextEditingController modelController;
  late FocusNode brandFocusNode;
  late FocusNode modelFocusNode;
  late FocusNode rgFocusNode;

  // List<VehicleListModel> vehicleList = [];

  List<String> vehicleType = [
    "Auto",
    "E-Rickshaw",
    "Motorcycles",
    "Cars",
    "Trucks",
    "Buses",
    "Others",
  ];
  String dropDownValue = "Cars";

  // get updateVehicleDetails => null;

  // get storedVehicles => null;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    print("object");
    registrationNumberController = TextEditingController();
    brandController = TextEditingController();
    modelController = TextEditingController();
    rgFocusNode = FocusNode();
    brandFocusNode = FocusNode();
    modelFocusNode = FocusNode();

    super.onInit();
  }

  addVehicleApiCall() {
    customLoader.show();
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    if (brandController.text.isEmpty ||
        modelController.text.isEmpty ||
        registrationNumberController.text.isEmpty ||
        rgFocusNode.hasFocus == false) {
      Get.snackbar(
        "error",
        "Every field must be  filled",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
      );
      customLoader.hide();
      return;
    }
    var loginReq = {
      "model_number": modelController.text,
      "registration_number": registrationNumberController.text,
      "vehicle_type": dropDownValue,
      "images": '',
      "user": '1',
    };
    // Get.find<PostApiServiceImpl>()
    //     .postVehicleApiCall(dataBody: loginReq)
    //     .then((value) async {
    //   vehicleList = value;
    //   customLoader.hide();
    //   toast(registerResponseModel.message);
    //   storage.write(LOCALKEY_token, value.accessToken);
    //   storage.write(RefreshToken, value.accessToken);
    //   storage.write(LoginModelStKey, value.userDetails);
    //   storage.write(isFirstTime, false);
    //   Get.offAllNamed(AppRoutes.addVehicle);
    //   // Get.offAndToNamed(AppRoutes.homeScreen);
    // }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
    //   customLoader.hide();
    //   toast(error.toString());
    // });snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP
  }
}


I Do not able understand to the main issue in this code where i just derieved all things why am i getting ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#e199a]:
Null check operator used on a null value this error.
can you resolve to the main cause where i am faulting though?
